# Variables in the sudoer file

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, sudo, environment-variables

I am trying to set up a cp command in my sudoers file to run without a password for some users. The directory I will copy to's name is unknown. I know the path to it, but the directory itself is a variable (my machine named it as the hostname, but I will need to put this sudoer file on other machines with different hostnames). Is there a way the sudoers file can fetch the hostname and/or an environment variable holding the hostname?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Why not give permissions to users to directories?

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem